# Segfault only when enabling -O2 optimization flag

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++20

I encountered a issue from a larger c++ application that only happens when optimizations are enabled `-O`, `-O2` or `-O3`. I managed to reproduce the problem with the following simplified code snipet:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

class PriceFeedStream {
   private:
    std::string trades_file_name = "example.csv";
    std::ofstream output_trades_file;
   public:
    PriceFeedStream(const std::string& assetName){
        std::cout << "trying to initialize " << std::endl;
        output_trades_file.open(trades_file_name, std::ios::app);
        if (!output_trades_file) {
            std::cerr << "failed to open file: " << trades_file_name << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        output_trades_file << assetName << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::string asset = "ABC3";
    std::cout << "initializing feed map with asset " << asset << std::endl;
    std::unique_ptr<PriceFeedStream> feed = std::make_unique<PriceFeedStream>(asset);
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The application is compiled on Windows, using the compiler version:

```
g++.exe (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-mcf-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 13.2.0
```

When compiling without any optimization flags:

```
g++ -g -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++20 main.cc -o main
```

the output from running the executable is:

```
initializing feed map with asset ABC3
trying to initialize example.csv
done
```

Compiling with optimization flags enabled:

```
g++ -g -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++20 -O2 main.cc -o main
```

produces the following result when running the executable:

```
initializing feed map with asset ABC3
Segmentation fault
```

My guess is that the code might have some undefined behavior, leading to this segfault that doesn't appear without the optimization flags. I would like to understand what type of issue this is in order to mitigate in future scenarios.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Remove all the code associated with `std::fstream output_trades_file = std::fstream();` and also that member variable.  Does your code crash?

Comment: if possible try to reproduce the issue without the `ifstream`. If you cannot reproduce it without input, try to read the input from a stringstream that can be included in the code

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie when removing everything related to the fstream, the code runs without issues.

Comment: Your constructor does a lot of work that I wouldn't do in a constructor (opening files), and especially when you are constructing an object that will be used in the `std::make_unique` call.  Also, having stream objects as members of a class is a code smell.

Comment: Remark: if file is opened in append mode, seeking before writing to it is of no effect.

Comment: @user12002570 I did pass it on GDB without much luck to understand the actual issue, i have located where the problem is, it breaks when invoking the constructor for the PriceFeedStream, no much more. Let me know if you have any tips on how would you approach debugging this types of problems.

Comment: You never specified if you open for  writing or reading, you should specifiy std::ios::out | std::ios::app, at least (in your case). Aside: If your intent is to write only, why not use ofstream?

Comment: I guess ofstream doesnt have .seekg, but it might have something similar, would have to look into it for a improvement.

Comment: @victorfts If opened in app mode, seekg is of no interest!

Comment: What if you make it an `ofstream` instead and drop the useless `seekg`?

Comment: I'm not sure if MinGW-W64 supports it, but you could also try adding the compilation options `-fsanitize=address,undefined` and re-run the program to see if that catches anything interesting.

Comment: Changing to ofstream and droping the seekg still doesnt, doesnt solve the issue.

Comment: No luck with the `-fsanitize=address,undefined` , probably not supported:
```bash
g++ -g -Wall -Werror -Wextra -fsanitize=address,undefined -std=c++20 -fopenmp -O2 main.cc -o main
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lasan: No such file or directory
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lubsan: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Removing the `fstream`  removes the crash - is the `std::map` needed? It seems you could remove half the program and just use `PriceFeedStream("ABC")` for the testcase. See [mcve]

Comment: @MSalters the point of this example is using the map, it is part of a larger codebase, this in only a simplified example, we cant really drop the map, the complexity it adds might be relevant to the bigger issue.

Comment: @victorfts The question is if you can reproduce the issue even if you drop the map

Comment: @TedLyngmo the issue persists when removing the map, but still retaining the unique_ptr

Comment: Ok, please continue removing stuff not needed to reproduce the issue. Update the question with what's left.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown code. Compiler bug, or library bug, or mismatch between the compiler and the c++ library.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik any tips on how would we fix the issue if its not directly code related ? still not getting into why would it work without the optimization flags

Comment: *still not getting into why would it work without the optimization flags*  If the bug is due to **undefined behavior**, when the program is optimized the *as-if* rule may optimize the code under the assumption that the source is not ill-formed, and does not have undefined behavior.  But if the source is ill-formed and does have undefined behavior, the optimized program may trip over that problem. And even though the unoptimized code appears to work as expected — it's still broken.

Comment: Change this:  `std::unique_ptr<PriceFeedStream> feed = std::make_unique<PriceFeedStream>(asset);` to this: `PriceFeedStream *p = new PriceFeedStream(asset);` or even this: `PriceFeedStream feed(asset);`-- Does it crash now?

Comment: In the past when I encountered a rare compiler bug I had limited success in narrowing down what trips the bug and then work my code around it. There is no general, paint-by-numbers, cookie-cutter recipe for this. Every situation is unique. Unfortunately, the situation you find yourself in is very fertile ground for breeding these kinds of bugs: an alien compiler that's ported to a foreign operating system that it wasn't originally designed for. Not entirely unsurprising, for something like this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was indeed related to the choice of compiler as mentioned by @SamVarshavchik, not sure of the root cause. I installed Clang/LLVM on the same windows machine.

```bash
clang --version
(built by Brecht Sanders) clang version 16.0.6
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:/mingw64/bin
```

and after compiling the code with

```
clang++ -g -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++20 -O2 main.cc -o main
```

the application executes as expected:

```
initializing feed with asset ABC3
trying to initialize
done
```

Comment: Please specify _which_ compiler bug was identified as the problem, preferably with a link.  This will be much more informative to others experiencing the same symptoms.

Comment: I am not a compiler maintainer, but merely compiling with a different compiler I wouldnt take as evidence for a compiler bug. I mean you did more, like checking the code back and forth, ppl were using santizers etc. Just saying that just because there is no segfault with Clang does not directly imply a bug in the other compiler

Comment: I am not sure exactly what is the root cause of the issue @TobySpeight, i have updated the answer to reflect that, but i have tested with a new compiler on the same machine and also in another OS, in both cases it yields successfull results.

Comment: My guess would be a libstdc++ runtime dll mismatch, make sure your application is using the version matching your compiler, not some other dll from somewhere on your path

Comment: @victorfts Re: _"I am not sure exactly what is the root cause"_ - If you had continued to remove and simplify your code and updated your question with the absolute minimal example, you may have found out what class and/or (member) function it is that causes it. It would also make it possible to write a good Issue on the port of gcc - or search for existing issues.

Comment: I am still trying to dig into the root cause of the issue @TedLyngmo, will update the answer as soon as I find out more.

Comment: @victorfts You should update the _question_ with a [mre]. Removing everything not needed to reproduce the issue shouldn't be that hard in that program.